# C# Passing reference to class in constructor

Tags: c#, class, reference

I want to pass a reference to a setting to a class when I create a new instance of the class. The should then under certain circumstances change the setting that was supplied. However when I try to do this I get "Cannot use ref or our parameter 'setting' inside an anonymouse method, lamda expression or query expression"

```
class MyClass {
    private int setting;

    public MyClass(ref int setting) {
        SomeOtherClass someOtherClass = new SomeOtherClass();

        someOtherClass.SomeEvent += (s, e) => {
            setting = someOtherValue;
        };
    }
}
```

Im the application I have to use the "MyClass" a lot, and it seemed foolish to have to write the event handler for every instance, when only the setting was different between each instance.

Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Comment: `ref` simply doesn't work like that. It's basically only "valid" for the duration of the method call. Imagine you called the `MyClass` constructor with a local variable reference... how would you expect that to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyClass {
    private int setting;

    public MyClass(Action<int> onNewSetting) {
        SomeOtherClass someOtherClass = new SomeOtherClass();

        someOtherClass.SomeEvent += (s, e) => {
            setting = someOtherValue;
            onNewSetting(setting);
        };
    }
}
```

And in Main (or elsewhere):

```
int local = 0;
var m = new MyClass(i => local = i);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, did exactly what I wanted. :)

Answer (score 0):

Pass a delegate with lambda expression:

```
class MyClass 
{
    private int setting;

    public MyClass(ref int setting) 
    {
       SomeOtherClass instance = new SomeOtherClass(s => setting = s);
    }
}


class SomeOtherClass
{
    Action<int> changeValue;
    public SomeOtherClass(Action<int> method) { changeValue = method; }    

   // invoke it and pass new value where you need it :
   // void SomeWhereInCode() { changeValue(100); }
}
```